# Mixing 32-bit JDBC with 64-bit database on same server

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, 64-bit, 32-bit

We are running Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit), SQL Server 2008 R2 (64-bit) and a 32-bit Java application all on the same server.  The application uses the Microsoft JDBC Driver v3.  The application can use Java 5 or Java 6, but both as 32-bit JRE's.  So the driver can be type 3 or type 4.

Here's what we see:  When the application runs, database access can become quite slow when under any type of load.  When you remove the load, it will be okay.  Put it under load again, and it becomes slow.

The complex part of this is:  If we run the application on a separate but equal server from the database, it is not slow.

So it appears that the behavior of the driver is different.  When driver and database are on the same server (reached through the local stack), then the mix of 32-bit and 64-bit slows things down.  When the driver and database are separate from each other (reached through the network), then the mix does not cause a slow down.
Any thoughts?

We do not expect the application and database to be on the same server.  But we have sales people who demonstrate on a single laptop, so they need it all together.  Currently, we look like we will be forced to isolate using VM's or similar.  Not what sales wants.
Technically, we are curious why introducing the network makes a difference.

Comment: This has been resolved.  We analyzed code going against SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2, also on the same machine as the application.  We found that with 2008 R2 it was necessary to add "pauses" into the logic surrounding the JDBC actions.  By inserting these sleep times, we seem to have given enough time to something else that needed the CPU.  We do not know what was requiring the added cycles, and probably won't pursue this further.  We see the impact only when the JDBC Driver (32-bit) is communicating to the database (64-bit) on the same machine.